# How to Password Protect a Document in SharePoint?

Tags: document-library, pdf, password, document-center

HR started uploading lots of personel pdf documents to their tight controlled SharePoint document center. HR have access and off course we in IT (shapepoint team) has access to personal pdf file (that has ssn, dob, etc.).

Is there a way to password protect all of those PDFs in SharePoint? If yes, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have Acrobat, you can protect your PDF files with password. Maybe this link can help you.

http://www.adobe.com/products/acrobat/pdf-file-password-permissions.html

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is a way to do this with standard SharePoint functionality. I would use a third party Tool such as Aspose.PDF to set passwords on the PDF files.

Comment: That's what I meant 3rd or codeplex solution for this aspose is very expensive

Comment: There are other 3rd party products as well that can achieve exactly what you are looking for, see http://blog.muhimbi.com/2010/12/securing-pdf-files-using-sharepoint.html and http://blog.muhimbi.com/2012/05/apply-user-specific-pdf-security-when.html. Note that I have worked on this product so I am obviously biased.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you can with a PDF, but you could always save it as a Word document and use the feature inherent within Word. Secondarily, why not keep these files hidden with regular SP security features. At my work, we've had the same discussion about PII and found this option works quite well. Nobody but those in the security group or admin can even get to the information in the first place.